# How can I get closed date from today with sorting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sort a SQL table by closest date from today.

Heres an example table.

```
ID          Name          EVENTDATE (datetime)
1           test          2019-07-01 00:00:00
2           test          2020-03-21 00:00:00
3           test          2024-01-01 00:00:00
4           test1         2016-02-14 00:00:00
5           test2         2017-05-03 00:00:00
6           test3         2014-03-23 00:00:00
```

The expected table I want by sorting is like this.

```
ID          Name          EVENTDATE (datetime)
2           test          2020-03-21 00:00:00
5           test2         2017-05-03 00:00:00
4           test1         2016-02-14 00:00:00
6           test3         2014-03-23 00:00:00
```

As you can see, it looks like descending sort.

Yes, in normal its a descending sort.

But please see the above three rows with the same `Name` value `test`.

`test` value has three `EVENTDATE`s. `2019-07-01 00:00:00`, `2020-03-21 00:00:00`, `2024-01-01 00:00:00`.

In this case only one row is selected by the nearest day from today. (`2019-07-01` is already passed and `2020-03-21` is the nearest day)

Hope you understand what I want. (sorry for my bad English :D)

How can I handle this with SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `DateDiff` and `Abs` to calculate the distance from "today"? Are the `DateTime` values actually `Date` values, i.e. the time is always zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter *as well as* sort.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by abs(datediff(day, eventdate, getdate()))) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by t.eventdate desc;
```

Comment: Amazing! this is exactly what I want. Thank you.